# How is php.ini related to php.ini-development and php.ini-production?

Tags: php

In the PHP installation, there is php.ini, php.ini-development, and php.ini-production. I understand that the settings in php.ini are the ones that should be changed, so what are the other two for?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They are template files for you to copy over to your actual `php.ini` if you feel it matches your environment's needs.

- Development environment offers verbose messages and comfortable optional features, what you want when you're coding your scripts.
- Production environment is typically more minimalist (i.e. errors are logged rather than displayed, etc), for interacting with real users efficiently.