# how to set laravel php.ini location

Tags: php, mysql, database, pdo, laravel-5

I want to use mysql database with my laravel 5.2 framework. I'm not able to access phpmyadmin after I run 'php artisan serve' and open a localhost page.

My .env file :

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_DATABASE=people
DB_USERNAME=pftest
DB_PASSWORD="pftest_2016#9"
```

After doing this, I ran 'php artisan migrate' and got following error:

```
[PDOException] could not find driver
```

Following which, I have installed php-mysql extension and checked for its presence in php.ini file. But still I'm getting following error :

```
[PDOException]  SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused
```

So what is the issue and how to solve it ?
I was told to check for php.ini locaton. I did,and after I ran php --ini , I found the configuration file pointing at this place: /etc/php/7.0/cli/php.ini. Where is it suppose to point ?? how to know which path its suppose to point ??

I have been through the links below in order to find answer : 
[Set path to php.ini](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9269083/set-path-to-php-ini)

[How is php.ini related to php.ini-development and php.ini-production?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33937501/how-is-php-ini-related-to-php-ini-development-and-php-ini-production)

[Overriding global php.ini file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7781927/overriding-global-php-ini-file)

Comment: Does mysql is running on the default port 3306.?

Comment: @RajeshHegde how to check that ?

Comment: can you post the result of php -i | grep PDO -i - can you also post the relevant section of the laravel config file database.php?

Comment: `ps aux |grep mysql` to check mysql process

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer is addition to Ayaz's answer,

In .env file, set

APP_ENV=local
DB_PORT=3306

and the do php artisian migrate --env="local"

Same is valid for development,production environment.

Answer (score 1):

Yor are not define port in your .env file Db_PORT=3306

```
  DB_CONNECTION=mysql
  DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
  DB_PORT=3306
  DB_DATABASE=people
  DB_USERNAME=pftest
  DB_PASSWORD="pftest_2016#9"
```

Comment: check this link                                                              (http://www.johnshipp.com/php-artisan-migrate-laravel-5-pdoexception-sqlstatehy000-2002-no-such-file-or-directory-on-a-mac-using-mamp/)

Answer (score 0):

At the beginning of this file **bootstrap/autoload.php** yuo 
can try this file

Comment: ini_set('max_execution_time', 300); //300 seconds = 5 minutes what ever u want write

Comment: still the same error:   [PDOException]                             
  SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused

Answer (score 0):

```
     [PDOException]  SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused
```

The error message indicates that a MySQL connection via socket is tried (which is not supported).

In the context of Laravel (artisan), you probably want to use a different / the correct environment.

Eg: 
          php artisan migrate --env=production 
(or whatever environment). See here.https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/artisan#usage

Comment: which env is advised to be used? I'm not using laravel-homestead. And I have tried local,dev,production env all of them throw same error.